# Named pipes in c

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I am trying to use named pipes in C and am running into some difficulty. In terms of anonymous pipes, I just create the pipe with the r/w descriptors and then close the opposite end every time I want to do a read or write. This is easy to do since I can just open() and close() the other end every time.

With named pipes, I am a bit confused, I found the instruction `mkfifo()` which creates the named pipe but don't understand how to read and write to it properly.

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear. `open` is never used with plain (anonymous) pipes, so I wonder if you're doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: You could be missing the point that the fifo needs to be open at both ends with one writing and the other reading.  Any read/write call on fifo is blocking.  The man page is here http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo.  Otherwise you are not asking the question, simply stating your problem.  What code have your written and what is causing your confusion?

Comment: Read [Beej's Guide to Unix IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/).

Comment: For the anonymous pipes, I first create them using the pipe() function and then have one process reading and one writing to the pipe, but it has to close the other end first. It seems to work fine and is based on the example at http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html

Answer (score 4):

After the pipe has been created with `mkfifo()` (which could have been done at any point in the past - named pipes exist in the filesystem until they're unlinked), the reading side opens it using `open("/path/to/pipe", O_RDONLY)` and the writing side opens it with `open("/path/to/pipe", O_WRONLY)`.

After that it can be used just like an anonymous pipe.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing much to it.  Use mkfifo to make the pipe and then have your processes read and write to it like any file.  It's not C specific either.  You can do this:

mkfifo testfifo

cat testfifo

And then in another window

echo "hello, world" > testfifo

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just use the pipes, cause they handle the data transmission among the different processes no matter the time each proccess takes